# Jenkins Pipeline: Any strategy to schedule each stage with shell commands

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, scheduled-tasks, jenkins-groovy

I'm glad to use the Jenkins pipeline to automatically trigger some shell tasks and Jenkins jobs. wherein I had one blocker, I've researched many references but couldn't find any solution. Kindly provide if you've any for below.

Problem: Do we have any strategy to schedule each stage?

Description: I have a declarative pipeline where I'm triggering a set of shell commands in each stage, and I want to achieve scheduling each stage like below

```
pipeline{
  agent {label 'somenode'}
  stages{
    stage('first stage'){
      triggers{cron ('* * * * *')}
      steps{
        //Some shell commands
      }
    }
    stage('second stage'){
      triggers{cron('* 10 * * *')}
      steps{
        steps{
          //some other shell commands
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you've any other path rather than using triggers directive please share with me.

Comment: I think you might be trying to use jenkins for the wrong purpose,  this is a CI/CD software and you should use it as a secuence of operations that will deploy/tests certain code in a way that you have a repetable and consisten result. Yo can schedule a pipeline to run every X amount of time or triggered by an event like code being push to a branch but execute a pipe of asynchronus stages don't look like to be the right way to use it. Can you provide the complete scenario for this kind of need?

Answer (score 0):

Triggers directive is available in jenkins pipeline where you could put your cron condition but it will be executed for all the stages and not for a single stage.
If you need to execute the stage at a certain condition then you can use the `while` clause.
Please see below code / method which will give you an idea of how to execute specific stage at a specific day or at a specific condition.You can change the conditions based on your requirement.
Use plugin Timestamper https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/ to get timestamp releated infos.

```
# Get the day from the build timestamp
def getday = env.BUILD_TIMESTAMP
getday = getday .split(" ")
// Extract current day
getday = getday [3]
pipeline 
{
  agent any
 options { timestamps () }
 stages {
 stage('Stage 1') {
        steps {
            script {
                  // do something
                )
            }
        }
    }

 stage('Stage 2') {
      when 
            {
                // Note: You can change condition as per your need
                // Stage will run only when the day is Mon 
                expression {
                     getday == "Mon"
                }
            }
        steps {
            script {
                  // do something
                )
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**Configure BuildTimestamp:** If your build time stamp is not configured to get day information, then you can do it using below method
https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timestamp/
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Build Timestamp -> Click on Enable BUILD_TIMESTAMP.
Put Pattern as :**yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z EEE**

Comment: [Altaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065630/altaf), but this method cannot be used when we want to **automatically trigger** the stage periodically right? for instance today if I want to trigger **automatically** for every 1hour, what changes I need to do in the above script?

Comment: @ArunkumarG As metnioned in answer, Triggers directive is available in jenkins pipeline but only for complete pipeline and not for a specific stage.So you dont have a possibility of automatic trigger but you have a possibility to execute stage based on the specific condition.

Comment: I don't have any use-case as you have mentioned; because if we put a condition it is just like
trigger_pipeline_now -> check condition (maybe dates) -> if matches trigger the stage
but what I need is
trigger_pipeline_now -> check condition(maybe dates) -> if not matches then at input time schedule stage and trigger automatically.

Comment: @ArunkumarG I dont think that is supported